# Testing NB model

Tags: python, machine-learning, naivebayes

I'm having trouble using my Naive Bayes model. I have trained and tested it using 'data_a' to predict if a review is 'positive' or 'negative'. I now want to use the same model to predict whether some text ('data_b') is 'positive' or 'negative'. I don't want to have to re-train the model using data from 'data_b'. Is this possible?

```
# This is my function to train and test my model

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

def train_and_test(data, target):

    # Data
    data_train, data_test, target_train, target_test = train_test_split(data, target, test_size=0.4, random_state=2)

    # TRAIN & TEST MODEL
    model = MultinomialNB()
    model.fit(data_train, target_train)
    predicted = model.predict(data_test)
    comparison = df(data={'Predicted':predicted, 'Actual':target_test})

    # ANALYSE RESULTS
    acc = accuracy_score(target_test, predicted)
    acc_percent = round((acc*100),2)
    print('Using train test split, this model achieves an accuracy of: ', acc_percent, '%')

    # apply 5-fold cross-validation, measuring accuracy each time
    acc_scores = cross_val_score(model, data, target, cv=10, scoring="accuracy")
    accuracy_10fold = round((sum(acc_scores)/10)*100,2)
    print('Using 10 fold cross-validation, the model achieves a mean accuracy of: ', accuracy_10fold, '%')

    return comparison
```

I would hope to change this function to:
def train_and_test(training_data, target_data, test_data, test_target):

Comment: I recon you test it and see if it returns an error or result with x percent correct or something. If an error might occur update your question with it. Use ">" for the yellow box. I also assume some robustness with the code that you can give a few parameters for sigma (standard deviations).

Comment: Another approach is to train with both types of reviews at the same time in one go. Then you should be fine  for both types of reviews.